# Php to post on facebook fan page not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

All,

I'm trying to post on facebook fan page directly with below PHP code. It is posting as "Post on pages" and it is shown at the side. Currently I have a wordpress plugin which post directly to the facebook fan page and want to replicate the same. Could you please check and let me know on what to be update on this.

```
<?php
// require Facebook PHP SDK
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/
require_once("/YOUR_PATH_TO/facebook_php_sdk/facebook.php");

// initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$fb = new Facebook($config);

// define your POST parameters (replace with your own values)
$params = array(
  "access_token" => "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
  "message" => "Here is a blog post about auto posting on Facebook using PHP #php #facebook",
  "link" => "http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php",
  "picture" => "http://i.imgur.com/lHkOsiH.png",
  "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
  "caption" => "www.pontikis.net",
  "description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation."
);

// post to Facebook
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
try {
  $ret = $fb->api('/YOUR_FACEBOOK_page_ID/feed', 'POST', $params);
  echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is posting, but not "as Page" but "as User", you just need to use a Page Token instead of a User Token.

Information on how to create a Page Token:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

> Get User Token > Extend User Token > call `/me/accounts` to get Extended Page Token

You MUST use a Page Token in order to post "as Page" and you should use an "Extended Page Access Token" that is valid forever.